# PHP Based PDF Modification Framework / Package

Tags: php, pdf

I'm looking around to see if there are any php packages that would be helpful for creating a solution that is similar to how Cafepress.com handles their custom designs. Basically we are building a marketing portal where users can log in, select a PDF and then add custom text and graphics to it and then e-mail it out to a list of customers. Obviously we're going to need PHP, JQuery and some sort of image rendering library like IMAGEMAGIK, but just wondering if anyone had any further advice.

As always any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have had some success with DOMPDF. Although thats from DOM to PDF, not existing PDF to PDF.
http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/

Answer (score 0):

For the pdf modification part, I think you can use the [fpdi](http://www.setasign.de/products/pdf-php-solutions/fpdi/) library. I got to use it for some simple changes on a pdf (setting some fields for the user) and it worked pretty well.

The problem is you still have to display the pdf to your user and get what changes he wants. Maybe try to find some pdf to png tool.

But I don't think a php/html/javascript stack is a good solution for what you want to do. I'd check what Flash or Silverlight can offer if I was you.

Answer (score 0):

[wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf) is a command-line tool that converts html pages into pdf documents using a built-in Webkit (Safari) rendering engine. That is, you create an ordinary html page in php and then simply convert in to pdf. Quite practical!

Comment: This looks like a great solution, but seems to depend on if you have access to your server. We're running on rackspace cloud sites so I don't think we have the ability to install this.